# Get a value inside of a script in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm having this script and since I'm new to JavaScript I want to take the `trackid` from the Google Analytics script 'UA-101203313-3' 
To be more specifi i want this: const trackid = 'UA-101203313-3'. How to retrieve this?
Can you show me how?

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-101203313-3"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-101203313-3');
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to take it? You could save it to a variable.

Comment: Yes exactly this

Comment: Just write `const trackid = 'UA-101203313-3';` (and then use `gtag('config', trackid);` to avoid duplication)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you can't just do `const trackid = 'UA-101203313-3';`?

Comment: I want to retrieve the value from the script. :P

Comment: If you don't know what to do, could you at least try and write `pseudo code`?

Comment: This would all be a lot clearer if you gave us a quick summary of the business requirement here.

Answer (score 1):

So, It sounds like you want to scrape some text. You can do that by using this regex to match on the script `src` attribute

```
var trackid = text.match(/\?id=(UA-\d+-\d+)/)[1]
```

This way only works if the data is a string:

```js
const text = `<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-101203313-3"><\/script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

  function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
  }
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-101203313-3');
<\/script>`

var trackid = text.match(/\?id=(UA-\d+-\d+)/)[1]
console.log(trackid)
```

If the data is already embedded in the page, you can select the script tag and get it in a similar fashion:

```js
var trackid = document.getElementById('google-manager').src.match(/\?id=(UA-\d+-\d+)/)[1]
console.log(trackid)
```

```html
<script id="google-manager" async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-101203313-3"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

  function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
  }
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-101203313-3');
</script>
```

Comment: `const` is probably better here since the trackid surely won't be reassigned :)

Comment: I beat you to it.

Comment: I want to retrieve it from the script using a function and then store it in a variable

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Why can't you just hardcode the trackid as a variable in your code? Anyway, if you want to retrieve it from the script, you could save the entire script url in a variable `url`, and do `const trackid = url.slice(-15);`, since the 15 last characters are the trackid. I don't see how this is useful though.

Comment: Are you saying to want to scrape the web page for the value?

Comment: I have this script ok? which is a script written in javascipt. This will be different each time i call the server. I want to retrieve it from th script everytime the script is rendered

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn exactly

Comment: When do you 'call the server'? You could pass the trackid along in a `POST request`